# Having issues converting from XML to Oracle SQL statements using Python

Tags: python, sql, xml

So I am trying to create a function that converts basic XML programs to Oracle SQL Statements using Python. I am able to obtain the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_DETAILS(
  EMP_ID VARCHAR2(70),
  EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(70),
  EMP_SALARY VARCHAR2(70),
  EMP_DEPT VARCHAR2(70),
  EMP_JOB_ID VARCHAR2(70)
);
```

however, I wish to get the following output:

```
CREATE TABLE BANK_EMPLOYEE(
  EMP_ID VARCHAR2(30),
  EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(70),
  EMP_SALARY NUMBER,
  EMP_DEPT VARCHAR2(20),
  EMP_JOB_ID VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

below is a snippet of the following codes I have tried to implement thus far

Method 1:

```
 #Generate the CREATE TABLE statement
    create_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE {} (".format(root.tag) #start creatinf the sql statements to create a table with the name of the root tag
    for column in columns: #Iterate through each column in the table
        if data_types[column] == 'str': #Check if the data type of the column is a string
            create_table_sql += "{} VARCHAR2, ".format(column) #Add the column name and data type (TEXT) to the SQL statement
        elif data_types[column] == 'int': #Check if the data type of the column is an integer
            create_table_sql += "{} INT".format(column) # Add the column name and data type (INT) to the SQL statement
        elif data_types[column] == 'float': #Check if the data type of the column is a float
            create_table_sql += "{} DECIMAL(10, 2), ".format(column) #Add the column name and data type (INT) to the SQL statement
    create_table_sql = create_table_sql[:-2] + ");" # Remove the trailing comma and space, and add the closing parenthesis to the SQL statement
```

Method 2

```
# Define a dictionary that maps Python data types to SQL data types
    sql_data_types = {
        'str': 'VARCHAR2(70)',
        'int': 'NUMBER',
        'float': 'DECIMAL(10, 2)'
    }

    # Generate the CREATE TABLE statement
    create_table_sql = "CREATE TABLE {}(\n".format(root.tag)
    for column in columns:
        # Add each column and its data type to the CREATE TABLE statement
        create_table_sql += "  {} {},\n".format(column, sql_data_types[data_types[column]])
```

In both cases I don't seem to get the output I wish to get

***Edit***

below is my xml sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <EMP_ID>101</EMP_ID>
    <EMP_NAME>Marshall Walker</EMP_NAME>
    <EMP_SALARY>100000.00</EMP_SALARY>
    <EMP_DEPT>100</EMP_DEPT>
    <EMP_JOB_ID>IT001</EMP_JOB_ID>
  </EMPLOYEE>
<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS>
```

Comment: You've not shown a sample of the XML.

Comment: apologies i have added it now

Comment: The XML doesn't specify the data types at all, so where are you creating the data_types dict?  also, you say you want BANK_EMPLOYEE as the table name but you're taking the table name directly from the XML, so which is it?

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense.  The XML is data for one row, but you are trying to generate a DDL statement to create the table.  Are you supposed to infer the schema from a data row, create the table and then load multiple records?  The objective isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its not 100% clear what you are looking for, the only way to create the output is by guessing the data types in the example you shared.

**Note** that the output that is generated is not the one you shared in the post!

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

MAPPING = {
    str: 'VARCHAR2(70)',
    int: 'NUMBER',
    float: 'DECIMAL(10, 2)'
}

xml = '''<EMPLOYEE_DETAILS>
  <EMPLOYEE>
    <EMP_ID>101</EMP_ID>
    <EMP_NAME>Marshall Walker</EMP_NAME>
    <EMP_SALARY>100000.00</EMP_SALARY>
    <EMP_DEPT>100</EMP_DEPT>
    <EMP_JOB_ID>IT001</EMP_JOB_ID>
  </EMPLOYEE>
</EMPLOYEE_DETAILS>'''


def _get_type(data):
    is_float = False
    is_int = False
    try:
        float(data)
        is_float = True
        int(data)
        is_int = True
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if is_int and is_float:
        return int
    elif is_float:
        return float
    else:
        return str


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
emp_properties = root.find('.//EMPLOYEE')
print('CREATE TABLE BANK_EMPLOYEE(')
for idx, prop in enumerate(emp_properties):
    last_prop = idx == len(emp_properties) - 1
    if last_prop:
        print(f'\t{prop.tag} {MAPPING[_get_type(prop.text)]}')
    else:
        print(f'\t{prop.tag} {MAPPING[_get_type(prop.text)]},')

print(');')
```

output

```
CREATE TABLE BANK_EMPLOYEE(
    EMP_ID NUMBER,
    EMP_NAME VARCHAR2(70),
    EMP_SALARY DECIMAL(10, 2),
    EMP_DEPT NUMBER,
    EMP_JOB_ID VARCHAR2(70)
);
```

Comment: That helper function _get_type is a game changer, apologies I mistyped my SQL statements the output here is the one I wished for Thanks!